# Pygame display not responding

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda

I'm slowly trying to get to know pygame and write my first game in it and honestly, I didn't expect problems so early. So far I've only set a display, that is supposed to be there indefinitely (I just wanted to try it out):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

(width, height) = (1000, 700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
while True:
    pygame.display.flip()
```

But when the window appears it says it's "not responding". I tried deleting the loop so that display would just blink once and vanish, because programm would die immiedately after it's created, but I get the same "not responding" window. I'm using pygame 1.9.2 and python 3.5. I wonder if the trouble may be because of anaconda - the window is opened as subcart for anaconda by default.

Edit: So far I discovered that when I open it not from spyder, but just click on a file it works just fine. Is there any way to make it work by simple run and compile while in spyder or it's just how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your loop. For me the only time it isnt responding is when I click the X and this could be to do with the fact that pygame doesn't know what to do when that happens.

```
import sys

for evt in pygame.event.get():
        if evt.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: The program needs to regularly handle events or the os thinks pygame has crashed. That's why it works when you add `pygame.event.get()`. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/5110/event-handling#t=201612261318490992061

Comment: Ah, ok. My solution should work though, but that is the right explanation

Comment: Your indention is a little off but otherwise it should answer the question. If you could add a line or two explaining why this solution works it would be great! In my link you have a short explanation in the third bullet point of the first example and in the **ATTENTION** section in the second example.

Comment: Hi @Malcadicta if my anwser above or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Try This 


import pygame

(width, height) = (1000, 700)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.update()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():``
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```